# Google Maps for Flash idle event

Tags: google-maps, actionscript

i'm new to Google Maps Api. I compared the javascript and flash map events and found that there is an "idle" event in Javascript API. There is the following advice in the google docs:

> Note that you could listen to the
>   bounds_changed event but it fires
>   continuously as the user pans;
>   instead, the idle will fire once the
>   user has stopped panning/zooming.

But i haven't found such an event in actionscript API. There are ZOOM_CHANGED, DRAG_END, etc events, but nothing like "idle".
Am i missing something or this event was not ported to the actionscript api? As far as i understand, that is a really useful thing - to wait until a user stops at some viewport instead of immediate handling of all his pan/zoom actions (cause it will affect the performance and produce unnecessary requests for marker data). Maybe there is some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an "idle" event either. But listening to ZOOM_CHANGED and DRAG_END individually should give you same results. Is there a particular reason why you are looking to avoid these 2 events for a generic Idle event ?

I would argue that individual events are better 'coz they give you a finer resolution at understanding the events.